# asyncio socket Как можно с помощью asyncio "поместить" подключившегося клиента в класс

Tags: python, сокет, asyncio

Имею код в котором каждого подключившегося должно было бы помещать в отдельную функцию и обрабатывать их асинхронно, но я захотел включить всё в класс и сразу же из за self стала выскакивать ошибка - **TypeError: handle_client() missing 1 required positional argument: 'writer'**.

```
import asyncio, socket

class UserConnect:

#   async def __init__(self, reader, writer):
#       self.reader = reader
#       self.writer = writer


    async def handle_client(self, reader, writer):
        request = None
        while request != 'quit':
            request = (await reader.read(255)).decode('utf8')
            print(request)
            response = str(request) + '\n'
            writer.write(response.encode('utf8'))
            await writer.drain()
        writer.close()

async def run_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(UserConnect.handle_client, 'localhost', 15557)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(run_server())
```

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Сделать handle_client внешней относительно класса и в ней только создавать объект этого класса, передавая туда все параметры. Возможно стоит сделать какой нибудь список клиентов, куда помещать созданный объект (тогда еще предусмотреть процедуру удаления от туда объекта после обрыва соединения) А `__init__` класса пускай сразу запускает цикл обработки событий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно внести метод `start_server` в класс `UserConnect`:

```
import asyncio, socket

class UserConnect:
    # тут все как раньше

    async def start_server(self, host, port):
        return await asyncio.start_server(self.handle_client, host, port)


async def run_server():
    userConnect = UserConnect()
    server = await userConnect.start_server('localhost', 15557)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()
```

Или можно добавить метод `serve_forever` и делать все там:

```
class UserConnect:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    async def handle_client(self, reader, writer):
        ...

    async def serve_forever(self):
        server= await asyncio.start_server(self.handle_client, self.host, self.port)
        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()

async def run_server():
    userConnect = UserConnect('localhost', 15557)
    await userConnect.serve_forever()
```